# Is anybody using the Specter BDD Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, bdd, boo

I was reading the example chapter from [the book by Ayende](http://www.manning.com/rahien/) and on the website of [the Boo language](http://boo.codehaus.org/) I saw a reference to the [Specter BDD Framework](http://specter.sourceforge.net/).

I am wondering if anybody is using it in their project, how that works out and if there are more examples and/or suggested readings.

Just in case you are wondering, I'm a C# developer and so I plan to use it in a C#/.NET environment.

---

A few year later visiting this question. I think we can safely assume [Specflow](http://www.specflow.org/) and some others like [NSpec](http://nspec.org/) became the tools we are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using it, but I've seen demos of it. It's very nice.

Boo has a lot of interesting extensibility points in parsing and interpreting the language itself that make it ideal for writing frameworks like Specter. The end result is much nicer looking than you'd be able to get with languages like C#.

Unfortunately, the fact that Boo isn't "in the box" and can't simply be something you check into your source tree and use really holds it back here. It's a much heavier adoption cost than just picking a framework like NSpec.

Answer (score 1):

I have used it a little, I'm starting a new project right now and I plan on using specter. I'm really enjoying it.